# Ajax populating table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I want to append table  with  but problem is that it is not appending anything in table

```
<%@page import="database.FoodServiceDAO"%>
<%@page import="beans.categoryBean"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<table id="table_design">
<tr id="categorys">
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i just want to append the  bewteen Table  ajax code for it is as following, the problem is that is not populating anything in

```
$(function () {

var $categorys = $('#categorys');
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET' ,
    url: '/controller?action=category' ,
    success: function(categorys){
        $.each(categorys, function(i, categorys){

            $categorys.append("<td><h1>Heelo</h1></td>") ;

        });

    }

    });
 });
```

Comment: From a quick look, I'd suspect a scope problem (that the `$categorys` variable is not visible within the `success` handler). Try to move it inside the handler.

Comment: It still not working, i move it within succes handler. :(

Comment: Well, I'd add some logging (`console.log(...)`) into the handler and the `$.each()` cycle to see if it is processed and what are the data.

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #$category in debug

Comment: What are you getting in the `categorys` inside success. Do a `console.log(categorys)` and post here.

Comment: It start working i simple add the jquery within the page rather calling it from other javascript  file.